# MySQL update fields based on value in another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a field based on the presence of a string in another field. I need to do this for hundreds of search strings. This is what I have thus far:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

UPDATE business_table
SET `chain` = '7-Eleven'
WHERE business_name LIKE BINARY '%7-Eleven%' OR business_name LIKE 
BINARY '%7 Eleven%';

UPDATE business_table
SET `chain` = 'A&W'
WHERE business_name LIKE '%A & W%' OR business_name LIKE '%A&W%';

UPDATE business_table
SET `chain` = 'Blenz Coffee'
WHERE business_name LIKE BINARY '%Blenz Coffee%';

UPDATE business_table
SET `chain` = 'Booster Juice'
WHERE business_name LIKE BINARY '%Booster Juice%';

UPDATE business_table
SET `chain` = 'Boston Pizza'
WHERE business_name LIKE BINARY '%Boston Pizza%';

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I tried putting this into a stored procedure without disabling SQL_SAFE-UPDATES as follows:

```
UPDATE business_table b
SET `chain` = '7-Eleven'
WHERE b.id = (SELECT id FROM b WHERE business_name LIKE BINARY '%7-Eleven%' OR business_name LIKE BINARY '%7 Eleven%');
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'b' for update in FROM clause
```

So I understand what this error is but I don't know how to get around it in my case; with hundreds of UPDATE statements.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only because your `update`s require full table scans.  The use of `like` with wildcards at the beginning of the pattern prevents any useful indexing.

So, you can do:

```
UPDATE business_table
    SET chain = (CASE WHEN business_name LIKE BINARY '%7-Eleven%' OR business_name LIKE 
BINARY '%7 Eleven%' THEN '7-Eleven'
                      WHEN (business_name LIKE '%A & W%' OR business_name LIKE '%A&W%') THEN 'A&W'
                      . . .
                 END)
    WHERE (business_name LIKE BINARY '%7-Eleven%' OR business_name LIKE 
BINARY '%7 Eleven%') OR
          (business_name LIKE '%A & W%' OR business_name LIKE '%A&W%') OR
          . . .
```

You need to fill in the rest of the conditions in the `WHERE` and the conditions in the `CASE`.